# Netsuite Transform Invoice to Custom Record Scheduled Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am attempting to create a script that will transform an invoice record into a custom record based on a `Scheduled Script`.
I have the saved search created however I receive an error when uploading the `script`:

> Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"missing ) after argument list (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#57)","stack":[]}

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/search', 'N/record', 'N/email', 'N/runtime'],

    function(search, record, email, runtime) {
        function execute(context) {
            if (context.type !== context.InvocationType.ON_DEMAND)
                return;
            var searchId = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter("custscript_searchid"); //add from script deployment
            try {
                search.load({
                    id: searchId
                }).run().each(function(result) {
                    log.debug({
                        details: 'creating invoice to email record from INV: ' + result.id
                    });
                    var invoiceToEmail = record.transform({
                        fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                        fromId: result.id,
                        toType: record.Type.customrecord_invoice_to_email,
                        isDynamic: false
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_email_template,
                        value: //add internal id of email template to use
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_invoice_number,
                        value: result.id
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_script_error,
                        value: //create variable for script error
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_ap_contact_email,
                        value: //populate from result information
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.save();
                })
            } catch (e) {
                log.error({
                    title: e.name,
                    details: e.message
                });

            }
            return {
                execute: execute
            };
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it's something I've done, it's still a work in progress as I haven't defined values for the set values yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a ")" in very end

```js
define(['N/search', 'N/record', 'N/email', 'N/runtime'],

    function (search, record, email, runtime) {
        function execute(context) {
            if (context.type !== context.InvocationType.ON_DEMAND)
                return;
            var searchId = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter("custscript_searchid"); //add from script deployment
            try {
                search.load({
                    id: searchId
                }).run().each(function (result) {
                    log.debug({
                        details: 'creating invoice to email record from INV: ' + result.id
                    });
                    var invoiceToEmail = record.transform({
                        fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                        fromId: result.id,
                        toType: record.Type.customrecord_invoice_to_email,
                        isDynamic: false
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_email_template,
                        value: //add internal id of email template to use
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_invoice_number,
                        value: result.id
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_script_error,
                        value: //create variable for script error
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                        fieldId: custrecord_ap_contact_email,
                        value: //populate from result information
                    });
                    invoiceToEmail.save();
                })
            } catch (e) {
                log.error({
                    title: e.name,
                    details: e.message
                });

            }
            return {
                execute: execute
            };
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your script, either in the top level script itself or one of the included modules. Fix the syntax error(s) and your script will upload successfully.

Develop your code in a good IDE like WebStorm that can highlight JavaScript syntax errors to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'll download that now.  Do you prefer webstorm over eclipse?

Comment: I do personally, yes, but I always advocate using what you know and what you're most productive in. Eclipse and WebStorm both have officially supported NetSuite plugins, although I believe the Eclipse support is ending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter value for three fields. Refer questions (????) marks in below code.:

```
  });
                var invoiceToEmail = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                    fromId: result.id,
                    toType: record.Type.customrecord_invoice_to_email,
                    isDynamic: false
                });
                invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                    fieldId: custrecord_email_template,
                    value: **????**//add internal id of email template to use
                });
                invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                    fieldId: custrecord_invoice_number,
                    value: result.id
                });
                invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                    fieldId: custrecord_script_error,
                    value: **????** //create variable for script error
                });
                invoiceToEmail.setValue({
                    fieldId: custrecord_ap_contact_email,
                    value: **????** //populate from result information
                });
                invoiceToEmail.save();
```

Comment: Thanks Sid, I had just removed those before uploading on Stack Overflow but I'll include them on the suitescript upload.